# Why does enabling play.PlayScala plugin lead to "sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression"?

Tags: playframework, sbt

I'm trying to add play scala as a dependency in `build.sbt`:

```
name := "name" 

version := "0.0" 

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(play.PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.2" 

resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal

organization := "com.suredbits.core"

libraryDependencies ++= {  
    val sprayV = "1.3.2"
    val akkaV = "2.3.8" 
    Seq(
      "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.0",
      "io.spray"            %%  "spray-can"     % sprayV withSources() withJavadoc(),
    "io.spray"            %%  "spray-routing" % sprayV withSources() withJavadoc(),
    "io.spray"            %%  "spray-testkit" % sprayV  % "test" withSources() withJavadoc(),
    "com.typesafe.akka"   %%  "akka-actor"    % akkaV withSources() withJavadoc(),
    "com.typesafe.akka"   %%  "akka-testkit"  % akkaV   % "test" withSources() withJavadoc(),
    "org.specs2"          %%  "specs2-core"   % "2.4.7-scalaz-7.0.6" % "test" withSources() withJavadoc(),
      "org.scalactic"               %%  "scalactic" %   "2.2.1" % "test" withSources() withJavadoc(),
      "io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.3.0" withSources() withJavadoc(),
      "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "1.6.0" withSources() withJavadoc() ,
    "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.10" % "test" withSources() withJavadoc(),
      "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "0.9.28" % "test" withSources() withJavadoc(),
    "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4" withSources() withJavadoc()
    )
}

testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-q", "-v", "-s", "-a")

parallelExecution in Test := false

logBuffered := false

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-feature")
```

Here is my `plugins.sbt`:

```
// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

//workaround for enablePlugins error in sbt  
//dependencyOverrides += "org.scala-sbt" % "sbt" % "0.13.7"

//Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.6")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.4.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.11.2")
```

and lastly here is my build.properties

```
sbt.version=0.13.1
```

I've read quite a few stackoverflow posts trying to solve this, including deleting the `~/.sbt` directory and then running `sbt` again and this didn't work.

The error message is as follows:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(play.PlayScala)
                                                          ^
sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
    at sbt.compiler.Eval.checkError(Eval.scala:384)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval.compileAndLoad(Eval.scala:183)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval.evalCommon(Eval.scala:152)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval.evalDefinitions(Eval.scala:122)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$.evaluateDefinitions(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:272)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$.evaluateSbtFile(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:110)
    at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$loadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:710)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1$1.apply(Load.scala:715)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1$1.apply(Load.scala:714)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:714)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadFiles$1$2.apply(Load.scala:721)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadFiles$1$2.apply(Load.scala:721)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at sbt.Load$.loadFiles$1(Load.scala:721)
    at sbt.Load$.discoverProjects(Load.scala:732)
    at sbt.Load$.discover$1(Load.scala:545)
    at sbt.Load$.loadTransitive(Load.scala:574)
    at sbt.Load$.loadProjects$1(Load.scala:442)
    at sbt.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:446)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$18$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:281)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$18$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:281)
    at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:91)
    at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:90)
    at sbt.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:140)
    at sbt.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:334)
    at sbt.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:289)
    at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:285)
    at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:276)
    at sbt.Load$.apply(Load.scala:130)
    at sbt.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:36)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:481)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:475)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:475)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:58)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:58)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:60)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:60)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:92)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:184)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:91)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:70)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:65)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:65)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:48)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:32)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:24)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:53)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:77)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:65)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:32)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`enablePlugins` isn't available in `sbt.Project` until sbt 0.13.5.

To upgrade have the following in `project/build.properties`:

```
sbt.version=0.13.5
```

Don't forget to stop `sbt` and start it over (or the version change won't get recognized).

For Play 2.2.x projects, you would replace

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(play.PlayScala)
```

with

```
play.Project.playScalaSettings
```

I'm pretty sure Play 2.2.x uses an incompatible version of Akka (2.2.x) with the one you're using (2.3.8). You might consider just using the latest Play 2.3.7. If you choose that route, you'll also need to upgrade to sbt **0.13.5** (or even the latest **0.13.7**).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! In my case I had forgotten to chechin the plugin.sbt and build.properties files in git. Remember to not .gitignore the entire projects folder.